# Non-manager reference

Tags: resume, job-search, references

I've been happily employed with a company in a technology-related job for several years now. However, as it is for many people, I've been offered another opportunity that I'd like to pursue.

My current job is my first real employment in my field. Thus, I am faced with a somewhat lacking list of references.

Although my relationship with my boss is excellent, it would be majorly damaged if I asked for a reference as they have no idea I am considering moving on.

Given that, my most relevant reference is now a manager from an internship several years ago; other than that I have only part-time and volunteer references.

**How would one generally go about improving a list of references when it is politically unpalatable to get a reference from one's current manager? My best idea to this point has been to ask another (senior) co-worker for a reference.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it happen. Your one and only reference may get hit by a truck, move to a desert island or get married and move with his true love to her country. You need alternatives. Get those senior co-worker references, especially if they are likely to rise to the management ranks before you do.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do that. I do have a few references, but they are less and less relevant...

Comment: @MarcelCharlemagne You'll get better ones over time, as your career advances :)